# Merging table without data using multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have 2 tables that It should look similar even the second table has not as many data as the first table. I want my table look like this.

[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \caption{A. By Layer}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{10}{Y}@{}}%{l*{10}{X}}
    \midrule
     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Model}} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Gaggl and Wright}}\\
     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Layer} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Layer}\\
     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
     \cline{2-5}
    \cline{7-10}
    \bfseries{ Moments}\\
     w  & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\\
     s  & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6\\
     k/n  & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7\\ 
     wb  & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8\\ 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \caption{B. Firm-Level}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{10}{Y}@{}}%{l*{10}{X}}
    \midrule
     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Model}} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Gaggl and Wright}}\\
     \cline{2-5}
    \cline{7-10}
    \\
    \bfseries{ Moments}\\
     wage   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{a} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{f}\\
     house  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{b} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{j}\\
     something e  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{c} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{l}\\ 
     wb & \multicolumn{4}{c}{d} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{m}\\ 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is my table

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want two tables (with different numbers)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I want my underline of table 2 for word 'Model' as long as underline of table 1 foe word 'Model' so it looks nice.

Comment: Yes,I thought so, but that does not answer my question: must they be distinct tables?

Comment: yes the tables must be distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mandatory to define the same number of columns that you use. You have defined 11 columns but only use 10. The problem is the columns without any data in table 2. They end up too narrow.

In example 1, I have used a fixed width `w`-column in table 2 and calculated the width manually to line up the rules with the rules in table 1. A ‘brute force’ solution that works if you have a relatively few tabulars, and do not change margin width too often.

In example 2, I have avoided manual ‘eyeballing’ by defining two fixed width columns (`Y` and `Z`), where `Z` is four times wider than `Y`. The trick here is fixed the width on all columns except the sixth. Since this is an `X`-column, [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/cabin) advance calculations secure that the table expands to exactly the line width. The number 11 is chosen because you have ten columns, and the first column is wider than the other. Depending on your document’s margins, 10 may work. With standard margins, using 10 in the formula gave overfull hbox-errors.

Both solutions give tables that (hopefully) look like the tables you request. These examples require an updated [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) package.

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \caption{A. By Layer}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{9}{Y}@{}}%{l*{10}{X}}
    \midrule
     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Model}} && \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Gaggl and Wright}}\\
     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Layer} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Layer}\\
     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
     \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
    \bfseries{Moments}&\multicolumn{9}{l@{}}{}\\
     w  & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\\
     s  & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6\\
     k/n  & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7\\ 
     wb  & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8\\ 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \caption{B. Firm-Level}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{9}{Y}@{}}%{l*{10}{X}}
    \midrule
     & \multicolumn{4}{wc{3.8cm}}{\textbf{Model}} & & \multicolumn{4}{wc{4cm}@{}}{\textbf{Gaggl and Wright}}\\
     \cline{2-5}\cline{7-10}
    \bfseries{Moments}&\multicolumn{9}{l@{}}{}\\
     wage   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{a} && \multicolumn{4}{c}{f}\\
     house  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{b} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{j}\\
     something e  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{c} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{l}\\ 
     wb & \multicolumn{4}{c}{d} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{m}\\ 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{wc{\dimexpr((\linewidth/11)-2\tabcolsep)}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{wc{\dimexpr((4\linewidth/11)-2\tabcolsep)}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{Z}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[th!]
  \centering
    \caption{A. By Layer}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}wl{2cm}*{4}{Y}X*{4}{Y}}
    \midrule
     & \mc{\textbf{Model}} && \mc{\textbf{Gaggl and Wright}}\\
     & \mc{Layer} & & \mc{Layer}\\
     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){7-10}
    \bfseries{Moments}&\multicolumn{9}{l}{}\\
     w  & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\\
     s  & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6\\
     k/n  & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7\\ 
     wb  & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8\\ 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[th!]
  \centering
    \caption{B. Firm-Level}
    \label{tab:table2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}wl{2cm}*{4}{Y}X*{4}{Y}}
    \midrule
     & \mc{\textbf{Model}} & & \mc{\textbf{Gaggl and Wright}}\\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){7-10}
    \bfseries{Moments}&\multicolumn{9}{l}{}\\
     wage              & \mc{a} && \mc{f}\\
     house            & \mc{b} & & \mc{j}\\
     something e  & \mc{c} & & \mc{l}\\ 
     wb                 & \mc{d} & & \mc{m}\\ 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. How do you now the width is 3.8cm? Is it manually try and error?. By the way, thanks for the answer especially for the word 'Moments'. I just realize that you make multicolumn for the rest unused column too, so it looks proportional.

Comment: @Yasrinayuliasari You are right regarding the width of the column. That is eyeballing. If you have lot of tabulars, this is not ideal, but it is the simplest and fastest solution if you have few and do not change page margins considerable. There are more than one possible and simple solutions do avoid this manual step, but it will depend on what type of information you are entering into the columns.

Comment: @Yasrinayuliasari I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the second option that more suit for my case.